# MKL not working on a C++ code that uses Eigen and OpenMP

Tags: c++, eigen, intel-mkl

I have a code with following structure :

```
Eigen::MatrixXd function1(args)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (args)
        //filling a matrix element-wise

    return matrix;
}

Eigen::MatrixXd function2(argument is function1 matrix)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (args)
        //element-wise probabilities calculations on matrix from function1

    return matrix;
}

Eigen::MatrixXd global_function(args)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd ident; //identity matrix

    for (args)
    {
        Eigen::MatrixXd mat = function1(args);
        Eigen::MatrixXd mat2 = function2(mat);
        ident = ident * mat2;
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

There are more functions, but the scheme is the same. Matrices are 500x500 to 1000x1000 in size
The code uses the libraries : Eigen (to build matrices) and Boost (for some probabilities calculations on function2), compiled using Visual Studio 2013 or Intel C++ compiler 15.0 (both have similar performance is my case)

I'm trying to implement Intel MKL for matrix-matrix multiplications :

So before implementing it in my code, I built a simple project to test MKL with Eigen and it worked (matrices are built with Eigen, while matrix-matrix multiplications use MKL, it reduced calculation time by half). I then implemented MKL into my code, but it didn't work this time, the calculation time didn't drop, what could be the reason ?

Comment: Please provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eigen can use MKL under the hood, so you could just use the Eigen interface for your matrices and let Eigen deal with MKL. 
All you have to do is `#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL` before you include any Eigen headers.

Comment: I already knew this, the problem is, it wasn't working for no apparent reason. But it worked the day after, so either I was stupid enough to believe that it wasn't, or the system reboot solved the issue for some reason.